# for how long `chrome.webviewTag` will be available in Electron, even if is already `"deprecated"` in Google Chrome docs?

Tags: google-chrome, webview, electron

May be I reached a wrong google webpage, but it looks like that `chrome.webviewTag` is already a `deprecated API`  : https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webviewTag/

If this is the case,  why `webviewTag` is still deployed in `Electron`?

The problem in a nutshell is the following: in the Electron docs it is stated that  : `" it's not guaranteed that the WebView API will remain available in future versions of Electron"` . And this while in the `Chrome Developers Docs` `webviewTag` looks ALREADY `"deprecated"`.

The main question is: for how long `chrome.webvieTag` will be available in Electron, even if, if I'm not wrong, it is ALREADY considered `"deprecated"` in Google Chrome docs ?
For the next 2 / 3/ 5  or 10 releases ?
Since the frequency of new Electron releases is, luckily, accelerated, this is a very important point